# Why is Subject<T>.HasObservers not guaranteed as true after SubscribeOn()?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Subject.HasObservers is not immediately true in the sample code attached for an undetermined number of ticks. If I take out the SubscribeOn(), HasObservers is always true, so I know it's to do with IScheduler initialization.

This was causing a problem in our production software where the first few calls to OnNext() were going nowhere despite a guarantee that the IDisposable subscription variable had been initialized before the thread that called OnNext() was allowed to proceed. Is this a bug in RX?

What are other ways to use System.Reactive classes to guarantee the subscription is setup with a scheduler without polling?

I have tried Subject.Synchronize(), but that made no difference.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var source = new Subject<long>();

        IDisposable subscription = source
            .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
            .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        // 0 and 668,000 ticks for subscription setup, but rarely 0.
        int iterations = 0;
        while (!source.HasObservers)
        {
            iterations++;
            Thread.SpinWait(1);
        }

        // Next line would rarely output to Console without while loop
        source.OnNext(iterations);
        subscription.Dispose();
        source.Dispose();
    }

}
```

I expected Subject.HasObservers to be true without polling.

Comment: It shouldn't come as a surprise that when you tell the observer to schedule things with the thread pool, subscriptions happen on the thread pool (and hence, not synchronously). Perhaps you're looking for `.ObserveOn` instead.

Comment: What do you expect that `.Synchronize()` does?

Comment: The help page for `ObserveOn` says it clearly: "Asynchronously subscribes and unsubscribes observers on the specified scheduler."

Comment: @Enigmativity: But is there a good way to know that the subscription operation in ObserveOn is really ready? What is the idiomatic way of achieving what the OP wants?

Comment: @Vlad - I'm trying to think of a way. I'm also trying to think of a scenario where you want asynchronous subscriptions with synchronous values.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, the problem is that your subscription is done *asynchronously*: the call is not blocked, so the real subscription will be done later on other thread.

I didn't find the exact way of knowing if the subscription has really landed (it might be even not possible at all). If your problem is the race between the first `OnNext` and subscription, than maybe you need to convert your Observable into a Connectable Observable using `Replay()` + `Connect()`. This way you'll ensure that every subscriber gets exactly the same sequence.

```
using (var source = new Subject<long>())
{
    var connectableSource = source.Replay();
    connectableSource.Connect();
    using (var subscription = connectableSource
                    .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
                    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
    {
        source.OnNext(42); // outputs 42 always
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
}
```

In my code I still need `Console.ReadKey` because of the race between subscription done on the other thread and unsubscription.

Comment: Agreed. I cannot find a way to use System.Reactive classes to listen for when the asynchronous Subscribe() has really landed without polling. Using Replay() is one solution, but then I'd need a way to clear it's contents. The solution I have come up with is to wrap Subject<T> which I will post.

Comment: @Mike: As a workaround, maybe one can specify buffer size of 1 or 1-second timespan for Replay?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with for now that I'm hoping someone can improve upon:

```
public class SubscribedSubject<T> : ISubject<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Subject<T> _subject = new Subject<T>();

    private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _subscribed = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    public bool HasObservers => _subject.HasObservers;

    public void Dispose() => _subject.Dispose();

    public void OnCompleted() => Wait().OnCompleted();

    public void OnError(Exception error) => Wait().OnError(error);

    public void OnNext(T value) => Wait().OnNext(value);

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        IDisposable disposable = _subject.Subscribe(observer);
        _subscribed.Set();
        return disposable;
    }

    private Subject<T> Wait()
    {
        _subscribed.Wait();
        return _subject;
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
using (var source = new SubscribedSubject<long>())
{
    using (source
        .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
        .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
    {
        source.OnNext(42);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```